# Iterating over a list of strings for operations in Python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, function, loops

I'm trying to do a rather simple loop in Python 3.6.1 that involves a list of strings. Essentially, I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
      X_out  Y_out  Z_in  X_in  Y_in  Z_in      
Year                                                                
1969    4     3     4      4     3     3
1970    2     0     1      3     2     2
1971    3     1     1      0     1     2
1972    2     0     0      3     1     0
```

and I'd like to find the net change of X, Y, and Z, making them new columns in this dataframe.

In its simplest form, this could be

```
df['x_net'] = df['x_in'] - df['x_out']
df['y_net'] = df['y_in'] - df['y_out']
df['z_net'] = df['z_in'] - df['z_out']
```

but in actuality, there are about fifteen columns that need to be created in this way. Since it'll be a bear, I figure it's best to put in a function, or at least a loop. I made a list of our initial "root" variables, without the suffixes that looks like this:

```
root_vars = ['x', 'y', 'z']
```

And I think that my code might(?) look something like:

```
for i in root_vars:
    df['%s_net'] = df['%s_in'] - df['%s_out'] %(root_vars_[i])
```

but that's definitely not right. Could someone give me a hand on this one please?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the relatively new ([Python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-498-formatted-string-literals)) [formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals):

```
for i in root_vars:
    df[f'{i}_net'] = df[f'{i}_in'] - df[f'{i}_out']
```

The `f` prefix before each string causes the `{i}` to be replaced with the value of the variable `i`. If you want the code to be usable in Python versions before 3.6, you can go with the more usual formatting:

```
for i in root_vars:
    df['{}_net'.format(i)] = df['{}_in'.format(i)] - df['{}_out'.format(i)]
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much, I really appreciate it!